# lidR: las_check deep = T failed while deep = F succeeds

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I want to run some test on a `LAScatalog` object using `las_check` with `lidR` in R.

The first run worked just fine (all flags were green) and when I tried to run the same
`las_check(ctg_bertrix, deep = T)`, I got the following error:

> Error: Trying to write an object of class list but this type is not supported.

How to interpret this error message? What should I do ? Does that mean that there is a problem with the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a bug.

Minimal reproducible example by setting an output files template

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ctg = readLAScatalog(LASfile)
opt_output_files(ctg) <- tempfile()
las_check(ctg, deep = T)
#>  Erreur : Trying to write an object of class list but this type is not supported.
```

Do not try to write the output and it works

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ctg = readLAScatalog(LASfile)
las_check(ctg, deep = T)
```